# Citation call-outs displayed as [?]

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm trying to write a big report Where I have a separated bibliography file.

When I execute latex/ Bibtex/ Latex /Latex -> the references are shown as `[?]` in my pdf file.

I'm using Texmaker.

file.bib :

```
@InProceedings{lan2009multiple,
  title={iiiiiiiiiii},
  author={iiiiiiiiiii},
  booktitle={iiiiig},
  pages={121--128},
  year={2009},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

main file :

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/aesm_edspia}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}%font modern
\rmfamily
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * cmr/bx/sc}{} %manque une police en lmodern
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{supertabular} 
\usepackage{epsfig, floatflt, amssymb}
\usepackage{moreverb} 
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[all]{xy} 
\usepackage{shorttoc} %
\shorttableofcontents{Titre}{profondeur}.
\usepackage{textcomp} %% pour le symbol pour mille par \textperthousand et degrés par \degres
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace} %interligne simple, double etc...
\usepackage{eurosans} %%pour le symbole \euro
\usepackage{epic,eepic}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash, textfont={footnotesize, singlespacing}, margin=10pt, format=plain, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %en tete chapitrage
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc} 
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{6}
\mtcindent=15pt

\newcommand{\ie}{c.-\`a-d.~}
\hbadness=10000% pb d'overfull box réglé
\hfuzz=50pt
\pdfcompresslevel9 % pour compresser le pdf final au maximum
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=5 % pour accepté les images PDF version 1.5 (ex: celles produites par Office 2007)
\def\underscore{\char`\_}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic {section}}
\renewcommand{\SC@figure@vpos}{c}% centrer verticalement le caption avec le package sidecap...
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\small\textbf{Figure~\thefigure}}
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}{\small\textbf{Tableau~\thetable}}
\newcommand\figcaption{\def\@captype{figure}\caption}
\newcommand\tabcaption{\def\@captype{table}\caption}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfig}
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand\figurename{\small\textbf{Figure}}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%pour revenir à 0

%%  1ere de Couverture:
\PresidentA{M. xx xxxxx}{}{Président}
\PresidentB{M. xx xxxxx}{}{Examinateur}
\RapporteurA{M. xx xxxxx}{}{Rapporteur}
\RapporteurB{M. xx xxxxx}{}{Rapporteur}


\makethese %% crée la couverture.
\onehalfspacing
%\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
%\baselineskip=18pt plus 1pt

% une page blanche (deuxième de couverture)
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{-5}
\null\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
%\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
%~\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Remerciements}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter.\thesection~ #1}}
\include{Resume/resume}
\include{Resume/abstract}
\include{Dedicace/dedicace}
\include{Remerciement/remerciement}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Liste des figures}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Introduction générale}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{Chapitre0/chap0}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter.\thesection~ #1}}
\include{Chapitre1/chapitre1}
\include{Chapitre2/chapitre2}
\include{Chapitre3/chapitre3}
\include{Chapitre4/chapitre4}
\include{Chapitre5/chapitre5}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\backmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Conclusion générale et perspectives}{}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Conclusion générale et perspectives}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{Conclusion/conclusion}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\backmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Liste de publications}{}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Liste de publications}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{Conclusion/listepubli}


\addbibresource{Biblio/biblio.bib}
\backmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Bibliographie}{}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Bibliographie}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\singlespacing
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliographie}

\bibliography{Biblio/biblio}
\end{document}
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Please convert your code snippet into a complete minimal working example (MWE) including the document class and required packages.

Comment: did you run bibtex?

Comment: Related: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/134144)

Comment: @ulrike Yes I did

Comment: What is the content of the blg-file?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with blg-file?

Comment: bibtex creates a log-file with the ending .blg, it should be in your folder. Open it with your editor and check the content.

Comment: Ah ok I find it  : "                                                                                                  
   This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: mathese.aux

A level-1 auxiliary file: Conclusion/conclusion.aux
The style file: Biblio/unsrtmodif.bst
Database file #1: Biblio/biblio.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "?"
(There was 1 warning)

Comment: Please, I'm still blocked in this problem are there any helps?